# React Native: Reverse Lazy loading/Paging in ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I am developing chat application. One feature is that user can retrieve chat histories like WhatApps or standard chat app. How can we implement reverse paging/lazy loading in ScrollView in React Native?

Comment: Are you planning to implement the reverse paging in `ScrollView` only?

Comment: @PrasunPal Yes, As of now I had planned to implement reverse paging in SrollView. As Chat bubbles/ Row item don't share one standard template view. Some chat bubbles are either of or combination of plain text, Image. GIF, PDF, Video, Audio and so on media types.